# How to add a string to os.system() command? (Python)

Tags: python, system

I like to add `tweet = "@idoodler My CPU temperature is " + str(CPU_temp)` to `os.system("sudo twidge update \"tweet\"")` (tweet is the tweet string above). Can anyone please tell me how I can add the tweet string to the os.system() command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd = "sudo twidge update \"{0}\"".format(tweet)
print cmd
os.system(cmd)
```

although to be honest you are probably better off using subprocess.call

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["sudo","twidge","update",tweet])
```